# C# - Efficient way of searching and replacing strings from a file

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a text file where I wish to search if a set of lines exists and update/overwrite them or if the set of lines does not exists, add them.

Here is the text file.

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
##NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.localhost"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.localhost
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.localhost"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.localhost"
    ServerName dummy-host2.localhost
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.localhost
    #ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the skeleton code. I first open the text file, and read it to the end so that I can use the Regex class. (I chose this because the code looks cleaner and concise rather than doing it the C way - looping). But it isn't that simple because I need to check first a set of lines.

```
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();

    // Replace the strings using Regex replace method
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path);
    writer.Write(content);
    writer.Close();
```

Given a port number, I appended it to this pattern

```
string virtualHost = "<VirtualHost *:" + cls_globalvariables.portNumber + ">";
```

And I used

```
Match match = Regex.Match(content, virtualHost);
```

to find the index of the search pattern. I also had to find the index of its closing tag  and replace them with an updated version of those lines. I have no problems of searching the ending line but I do have a problem of distinguishing the commented from uncommented lines.

Regex.Match returns the first occurrence of the search pattern which is the commented line. What I wanted to do was to search patterns without comments but how do I do that? I began thinking in C schemes such as looping character by character backwards and forwards starting from the match.Index until I detect a delimiter of "\r\n". Is there an efficient C# way to solve this?

Comment: Just skip over the lines with comments before calling `ReadToEnd()` by calling `ReadLine()` and checking if the line starts with `#`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it the way Jesse suggests, or if you want to stick to Regex, just put `^` at the start of your regex and set `RegexOptions.Multiline`.

> Multiline mode. Changes the meaning of ^ and $ so they match at the beginning and end, respectively, of any line, and not just the beginning and end of the entire string. For more information, see the "Multiline Mode" section in the Regular Expression Options topic.